# Problem with opening more than one Expansion Panel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with my application. The component ExpansionPanel of Material-ui is opening more than one Panel. I need to open just one.

father.js

```
      <div>
          {props.listContratos.map((item, index) => {
            if (item.ativo) {
              return (
                <PartesCardCollapse
                  listPartes={props.listPartes}
                  item={item}
                  key={index}
                  thunks={props.thunks}
                  hideSnackbar={props.hideSnackbar}
                />
              );
            }
          })}
        </div>
```

son.js

```
export default function PartesCardCollapse(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (expanded, panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root} onClick={getListPartes}>
      <ExpansionPanel
        expanded={expanded === props.item.id}
        onChange={handleChange(expanded, props.item.id)}
      >
```